# Cannot create a relationship between Employee and StateProvince

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I have an initial class **Employee** with two properties StateOfEmployment, SecondaryStateOfEmployment of the same entity which is **StateProvince**.

I'm having this error:

> {​​​​​​"Cannot create a relationship between 'StateProvince.Employee'
> and 'Employee.SecondaryStateProvinceOfEmployment', because there
> already is a relationship between 'StateProvince.Employee' and
> 'Employee.StateProvinceOfEmployment'. Navigation properties can only
> participate in a single relationship."}​​​​​​

My class

```
    public partial class Employee
    {
        public long EmployeeId { get; set; }
        public string JobTitle { get; set; }
        public string EmployeeCode { get; set; }
        public long? CountryOfEmploymentId { get; set; }
        public long? StateProvinceOfEmploymentId { get; set; }
        public long? SecondaryStateProvinceOfEmploymentId { get; set; }
        public string CostCenter { get; set; }
        public DateTime StartEffDate { get; set; }
        public DateTime CreatedTimestamp { get; set; }
        public string CreatedUser { get; set; }
        public DateTime UpdatedTimestamp { get; set; }
        public string UpdatedUser { get; set; }
        public bool IsDeleted { get; set; }
        public long ClientId { get; set; }
        public long PersonId { get; set; }
        public string CityOfEmployment { get; set; }
        public DateTime? HireDate { get; set; }
        public string BusinessUnit { get; set; }
        public string ManagerName { get; set; }
        public string ManagerEmail { get; set; }
        public long? EmploymentStatusId { get; set; }
        public long? EmploymentTypeId { get; set; }
        public string EmploymentTypeClientString { get; set; }
        public string HomeLegalEntity { get; set; }
        public bool Executive { get; set; }
        public string JobLevel { get; set; }
        public DateTime SysStartTime { get; set; }
        public DateTime SysEndTime { get; set; }

        public virtual Client Client { get; set; }
        public virtual Country CountryOfEmployment { get; set; }
        public virtual EmploymentStatus EmploymentStatus { get; set; }
        public virtual EmploymentType EmploymentType { get; set; }
        public virtual Person Person { get; set; }
        public virtual StateProvince StateProvinceOfEmployment { get; set; }
        public virtual StateProvince SecondaryStateProvinceOfEmployment { get; set; }

    }
```

And my context is

```
            modelBuilder.Entity<Employee>(entity =>
            {
                entity.Property(e => e.BusinessUnit).HasMaxLength(100);

                entity.Property(e => e.CityOfEmployment).HasMaxLength(100);

                entity.Property(e => e.CostCenter).HasMaxLength(100);

                entity.Property(e => e.CreatedTimestamp).HasDefaultValueSql("(getutcdate())");

                entity.Property(e => e.CreatedUser)
                    .IsRequired()
                    .HasMaxLength(100)
                    .HasDefaultValueSql("(suser_sname())");

                entity.Property(e => e.EmployeeCode).HasMaxLength(100);

                entity.Property(e => e.EmploymentTypeClientString).HasMaxLength(100);

                entity.Property(e => e.HomeLegalEntity).HasMaxLength(100);

                entity.Property(e => e.JobTitle).HasMaxLength(100);

                entity.Property(e => e.ManagerEmail).HasMaxLength(100);

                entity.Property(e => e.ManagerName).HasMaxLength(200);

                entity.Property(e => e.UpdatedTimestamp).HasDefaultValueSql("(getutcdate())");

                entity.Property(e => e.UpdatedUser)
                    .IsRequired()
                    .HasMaxLength(100)
                    .HasDefaultValueSql("(suser_sname())");

                entity.HasOne(d => d.Client)
                    .WithMany(p => p.Employee)
                    .HasForeignKey(d => d.ClientId)
                    .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.ClientSetNull)
                    .HasConstraintName("FK_Employee_Client");

                entity.HasOne(d => d.CountryOfEmployment)
                    .WithMany(p => p.Employee)
                    .HasForeignKey(d => d.CountryOfEmploymentId)
                    .HasConstraintName("Fk_Employee_CountryId");

                entity.HasOne(d => d.EmploymentStatus)
                    .WithMany(p => p.Employee)
                    .HasForeignKey(d => d.EmploymentStatusId)
                    .HasConstraintName("Fk_Employee_EmploymentStatusId");

                entity.HasOne(d => d.EmploymentType)
                    .WithMany(p => p.Employee)
                    .HasForeignKey(d => d.EmploymentTypeId)
                    .HasConstraintName("Fk_Employee_EmploymentTypeId");

                entity.HasOne(d => d.Person)
                    .WithMany(p => p.Employee)
                    .HasForeignKey(d => d.PersonId)
                    .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.ClientSetNull)
                    .HasConstraintName("FK_Employee_Person");

                entity.HasOne(d => d.StateProvinceOfEmployment)
                    .WithMany(p => p.Employee)
                    .HasForeignKey(d => d.StateProvinceOfEmploymentId)
                    .HasConstraintName("Fk_Employee_StateProvinceId");

                entity.HasOne(d => d.SecondaryStateProvinceOfEmployment)
                   .WithMany(p => p.Employee)
                   .HasForeignKey(d => d.SecondaryStateProvinceOfEmploymentId)
                   .HasConstraintName("Fk_Employee_SecondaryStateProvinceId");
            });
```

What am I doing wrong? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Use DataAnnotations such as ForeignKey attribute, if you use it you don't need to add any code to the OnModelCreate method:

```
    [Table("Employee")]

    public partial class Employee
    {
        [Key]
        public long EmployeeId { get; set; }

        [Column("JobTitle")]
        public string JobTitle { get; set; }

        [Column("EmployeeCode")]
        public string EmployeeCode { get; set; }

        [Column("CountryOfEmploymentId")]
        [ForeignKey("CountryOfEmployment")]
        public long? CountryOfEmploymentId { get; set; }

        [Column("StateProvinceOfEmploymentId")]
        [ForeignKey("StateProvinceOfEmployment")]
        public long? StateProvinceOfEmploymentId { get; set; }

        [Column("SecondaryStateProvinceOfEmploymentId")]
        [ForeignKey("SecondaryStateProvinceOfEmployment")]
        public long? SecondaryStateProvinceOfEmploymentId { get; set; }

        [Column("CostCenter")]
        public string CostCenter { get; set; }

        [Column("StartEffDate")]
        public DateTime StartEffDate { get; set; }

        [Column("CreatedTimestamp")]
        public DateTime CreatedTimestamp { get; set; }

        [Column("CreatedUser")]
        public string CreatedUser { get; set; }

        [Column("UpdatedTimestamp")]
        public DateTime UpdatedTimestamp { get; set; }

        [Column("UpdatedUser")]
        public string UpdatedUser { get; set; }

        [Column("IsDeleted")]
        public bool IsDeleted { get; set; }

        [Column("ClientId")]
        public long ClientId { get; set; }

        [Column("PersonId")]
        public long PersonId { get; set; }

        [Column("CityOfEmployment")]
        public string CityOfEmployment { get; set; }

        [Column("HireDate")]
        public DateTime? HireDate { get; set; }

        [Column("BusinessUnit")]
        public string BusinessUnit { get; set; }

        [Column("ManagerName")]
        public string ManagerName { get; set; }

        [Column("ManagerEmail")]
        public string ManagerEmail { get; set; }

        [Column("EmploymentStatusId")]
        public long? EmploymentStatusId { get; set; }

        [Column("EmploymentTypeId")]
        public long? EmploymentTypeId { get; set; }

        [Column("EmploymentTypeClientString")]
        public string EmploymentTypeClientString { get; set; }

        [Column("HomeLegalEntity")]
        public string HomeLegalEntity { get; set; }

        [Column("Executive")]
        public bool Executive { get; set; }

        [Column("JobLevel")]
        public string JobLevel { get; set; }

        [Column("SysStartTime")]
        public DateTime SysStartTime { get; set; }

        [Column("SysEndTime")]
        public DateTime SysEndTime { get; set; }

        [IgnoreDataMember]
        public virtual Client Client { get; set; }

        [IgnoreDataMember]
        public virtual Country CountryOfEmployment { get; set; }

        [IgnoreDataMember]
        public virtual EmploymentStatus EmploymentStatus { get; set; }

        [IgnoreDataMember]
        public virtual EmploymentType EmploymentType { get; set; }

        [IgnoreDataMember]
        public virtual Person Person { get; set; }

        [IgnoreDataMember]
        public virtual StateProvince StateProvinceOfEmployment { get; set; }

        [IgnoreDataMember]
        public virtual StateProvince SecondaryStateProvinceOfEmployment { get; set; }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Below should work,

```
 entity.HasOne(d => d.SecondaryStateProvinceOfEmployment)
                       .WithMany(p => p.Employee)
                       .HasForeignKey(d => d.SecondaryStateProvinceOfEmploymentId)
                       .HasConstraintName("Fk_Employee_SecondaryStateProvinceId").OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);
```

Comment: you mind sharing what does that .OnDelete do that would make it work?

Comment: You bind the same table twice to another table. When you try to delete relational table EF can't decide which one to delete. This way we say which one to delete.